# Date Range Filter is giving wrong Value

Tags: date-range, apache-superset

The Date Range Filter isn't performing as anticipated in apache superset. For instance, when selecting a time range from 2023-10-01 ≤ col < 2023-10-10, the expected output should display values from October 1 to October 9. However, it currently shows values from October 2 to October 10.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55rmO.png)

The Date Range filter displays values from October 2 to October 10 when the time range filter is set to 2023-10-01 ≤ col < 2023-10-10.